# if...else in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm a beginner at SQL and have this fairly easy conditional problem: Every installation number in the database has a customer. But I have been told that the customer is in either the AUDEB table or the AFORD table. I should first look in AUDEB for CUSTOMER_NO and use that if it is not NULL. If it is NULL, then take the CUSTOMER_NO from the AFORD table.

Use this if CUSTOMER_NO is not NULL

```
  SELECT CUSTOMER_NO
  FROM AUDEB
  WHERE INST_NO = 2
```

Else use this CUSTOMER_NO

```
  SELECT CUSTOMER_NO
  FROM AFORD
  WHERE INST_NO = 2
```

I see that there exist IF...ELSE condtions in SQL, but isn't there an easier way of selecting between the values from two queries where I want to use the first if the result is not null, else use the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `union` the tables using a subquery to retrieve a complete list of customers:

```
select  CUSTOMER_NO
from    (
        select  CUSTOMER_NO
        ,       INST_NO
        from    AUDEB
        union all
        select  CUSTOMER_NO
        ,       INST_NO
        from    AFORD
        ) as all_customers
where   INST_NO = 2
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution. I added 'AND KUNDENR is not null' to the WHERE clause to remove the NULL value if such exist. Also I should probably add the DISTINCT if the Customer number appears in both tables. That way I end up with a single row in all cases.

Comment: @Kasper Hansen - you don't need to use DISTINCT to get single rows, using Union alone would do it (without all)

Comment: will this not fail if there are rows in both tables matching the specifications ?

Comment: `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` will ensure only one record per `customer_no, inst_no` combination, provided that they are unique in the two source tables.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Well, the question says "the customer is in either the AUDEB table or the AFORD table"  If he can be in both, you could use `union` like Dems and Jcis suggest.  If `customer_no` can be `null`, you could filter that out with a `where` clause.

Comment: @Andomar you are right, I was distracted by the part about looking in AUDEB table first. But since it can only be in one table anyway, it is all fine

Answer (score 2):

If the two tables follow the same schema and there is no overlap in customrer_no you could use UNION:

```
SELECT T.CUSTOMER_NO
  FROM (SELECT CUSTOMER_NO, INST_NO FROM AUDEB
        UNION
        SELECT CUSTOMER_NO, INST_NO FROM AFORD) AS T
  WHERE T.INST_NO = 2
```

Or if the inst_no could be in both tables then join them (even if the schemas differ)

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.Customer_no, T2.CUSTOMER_NO)
FROM AUDEB as T1
FULL OUTER JOIN AFORD as T2
ON T1.INST_NO = T2.INST_NO
WHERE T1.INST_NO = 2 OR T2.INST_NO = 2
```

COALESCE will return the first non null result

Comment: In the second query, `outer join` is a syntax error.  Should be `full outer join` or `full join`

Comment: second surgestion will only work if INST_NO is unique in both tables

Comment: In the second suggestion, I changed the WHERE clause to 'WHERE T1.INST_NO = 2 OR T2.INST_NO = 2'. Else INST_NO was ambigous.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Just join both tables and use ISNULL() to get the value from the corresponding table.

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.CUSTOMER_NO, B.CUSTOMER_NO) AS CUSTOMER_NO
  FROM AUDEB A INNER JOIN AFORD B
    ON A.INST_NO = B.INST_NO
 WHERE A.INST_NO = 2
```

**Edit:** This assumes INST_NO is the primary key, but now it's been stated in comments that it is not. The OP should use the correct fields to join this 2 tables.

Comment: This is wrong. It will make the server overwork and give a wrong result

Comment: Why you think it is wrong? and what overwork? this is faster than using subqueries or Unions.

Comment: Inst_No does not appear to be the primary key. If there are 0 or several occurences of identical inst_no, joining on that is most likely to give the wrong number or rows returned. Also union all is usually faster than joining.

Comment: It assumes that there will be an INST_NO that equals 2 in both tables. That's why I suggest changing it to an outer join. Also I think joins are better than unions as it allows the schemas of the two tables to deviate in the future, it is a more robust solution imo.

Comment: t-clausen.dk, you are in fact right that INST_NO is not primary key. Instead they rely on the programmers to only insert 1 INST_NO in each table.

Comment: Well in many cases like this we only provide examples, the idea here is showing it could be done by joining both tables, it's the op who should add the correct fields to make this join work, we don't even know what are the rest of the fields in these tables so I just used INST_NO as an example.